# Hibernate: I want "on inserting into Table T1 , I want another column to be updated using a foreign key" . How is it possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm

Hibernate: I am inserting data into a table T1(a,b) , I want to update 'd' in table T2(a,c,d,e) using foreign key 'a'. How to write the hbm mapping file in both. It's a one-to-one relation.

```
Table T1(mac_id, cust_id)
Table T2(a,b, mac_id,c, status_id)
```

I want to update STATUS_ID to "assigned" if MAC_ID I inserted in T1, matches with  MAC_ID present in T2.

My foreign key is "MAC_ID".

Comment: Welcome do StackOverflow! Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour  Tell us what have you tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried using cascade property "save-update". It didn't work.

Comment: Please read documentation : [hibernate associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-associations)